# how to show MPMoviePlayer done button when video is playing?

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to play video in `MPMoviePlayerViewController`, it works fine and plays video but problem is that it does not show done button unless i switch to the full screen mode. It should automatically show player along with done button as shown in attached screen.[image]

here is the code:

```
   mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:myURL];
    [[mp moviePlayer] prepareToPlay];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setUseApplicationAudioSession:NO];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setControlStyle:2];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done button will be visible only when video is played in full screen mode. So, either you need to play the video in full screen mode using the following code:

```
player.moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
```

Or you need to customise the control to add your own Done button.

Comment: got it works but when video is complete the player close automatically i want that when video is complete player should not close automatically but should close on done click

Comment: Put some more code, where you got the notification when video is played successfully. And please accept the above answer if you satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Done button visible you set the ControlStyle.

```
[player.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
[player.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
```